# Python DataFrame .fillna() Recursion Error

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, fillna

I am working on a learning how to fill in NaN in a Python DataFrame. DataFrame called data containing an age column and only one row has an NaN. I applied the following:
data.fillna(data.mean(),inplace=True)

I ask to print out data and I receive a recursion msg.

My DataFrame only contains 4 rows if that is important.

I was expecting the DataFrame to come back with the NaN filled in with the mean value. I also tried replacing data.mean() with a number ex. 2.  Same error message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). For debugging help, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the input, expected output, and the full error traceback, in text format.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this was the correct thing todo or not but I cleared out the Kernel in Jupyter Notebook and ran it just fine.

Comment: "Not sure" should be comment not an answer